# INNER EXCEPTION #1: MSG: The underlying provider failed on Open. On Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, iis-10

I apologize in beforehand because I see that a lot of people have already answered this question but still I cannot find the answer , I am looking for.
I have one static class
Which has  static constructor

```
 public static class AppSettingsWrapper
{
    public static List<uspGetFilePath_Result> FilePaths = new List<uspGetFilePath_Result>();

    static AppSettingsWrapper()
    {
        using (MakEntities db = new MakEntities ())
        {
            FilePaths = db.uspGetFilePath().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

i am accessing this property FilePaths  from this function

```
     public static uspGetFilePath_Result GetUploadInfo(EnumHelper.FilePathDesc filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            return AppSettingsWrapper.FilePaths.Where(x => x.ID == Convert.ToInt32(filePath)).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

But some time whenver i call this fucntion i am getting this exception
The type initializer for 'PQCTrack.Utility.AppSettingsWrapper' threw an exception.

> System.TypeInitializationException
>
> INNER EXCEPTION #1: MSG: The underlying provider failed on Open., SOURCE: EntityFramework, FILE: , METHOD: Open, LINE: 0  INNER EXCEPTION #2: MSG: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server), SOURCE: .Net SqlClient Data Provider, FILE: , METHOD: TryGetConnection, LINE: 0  INNER EXCEPTION #3: MSG: The network path was not found, SOURCE: , FILE: , METHOD: , LINE:

So whenever this issue come i have restart the IIS app pool and then issue is resolved it does not come again

When i see the error logs i see that static constructor is called many a times,
becuase of which it is throwing error
Can any one tell me where the issue is?

Comment: Hmm, aside from your actual issue/bug/whatever it is extremely risky to do unchecked initialization tasks in a cctor (aka static constructors). If it throws an exception - like here, possibly -, your type will be unusable for the lifetime of that app-domain and any access will be greeted with a `TypeInitializationException`.

Comment: Thank u for replying but i am using  , using blocks when making data base call

Comment: I am not talking about resource cleanup. If you have connection issues at the time that query is executing, you _should_ encounter that issue.

Comment: ok , i don't think its a connection issue, becuase whenever this issue come i restart the application pool of IIS and then the issue is resolved it does come again

Comment: It could be caused by a memory leak/unclosed connections so that your connection pool is running out

Comment: Even i think its related to memory leak, consider that after GetUploadInfo triggers the constructor that fails, it's still adding entry  in the SystemLog table then how it is making sql connection that time and failing in in the constructor giving connection issue

Answer (score 1):

TypeInitializationException occurs when a static constructor has an error. It wraps the errors from static constructors. It cannot be reliably trapped outside of the static constructor.
I think that it can be when you call method `db.uspGetFilePath()` or in constructor `new MakEntities()` where you are using Sql connection. An error in the inner  exception: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible".
You must verifyed your Sql connection string.

Comment: This error comes randomly its not fixed, so i don't think is Sql connection string issue

Comment: I am using Entity framework  so MakEntities class is automatically generated by EF